# How can I convert input from an html form into a Java String variable?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications

I've created a .jsp file that is a form that takes in common information, e.g. name, address, email. I am using html forms along these lines:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

But how do I take the input and save it to a String variable? I then want to take that variable and pass into a class that creates client objects. This is my first web app I've tried to build and I am really struggling. Any help regarding taking user input for a web application would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Servlets to take the data from form.

Comment: I would use labels instead of text nodes.

Comment: `String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname")`.

Answer (score 0):

If I do something like this in other jsp page that i called in the form action :

```
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
```